# Extracting string from a txt file and sending in curl array

Tags: curl

I'm working on some code that searches a text file for a specific string of characters, then returns the rest of the characters in that line.

For example, inside the text file will be...

04/11 string1&string2

I want the code to search for "string1", recognise the "&" and return everything after, i.e. "string2". This then needs to be sent in a curl array.

This is what I have so far...with help from other questions...

```
$eventid = "string1";


$count = 1;
$handle = fopen("https://www.example.com/output.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $pos = strpos($line, $eventid);
            if ($pos !== false) {
                $text= substr($line, strpos($line, "&") + 1);
                echo $text;
                break;
            }
        $count++; 
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

This seems to do what I want and returns "string2" inside $text. But when I feed $text into the curl array and execute, I get an error in the response saying "The JSON format is invalid."

Here's a snippet from the curl code.

```
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{ "string": "'.$text.'"}',
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks

EDIT:

So when I was initially storing the two strings in the txt file, I had a PHP_EOL command at the end of the command so that the next entry would be on a new line. I think this command was adding a hidden value to the end of string2 and when I fed it into the curl array, it didn't like it. So I changed the way I stored the strings in the text file and had the PHP_EOL at the start of the command, followed by the strings. No more errors from curl.

EDIT2: Following on from misunderstoods comments...

This is how the output.txt file is generated.

```
$filename = 'output.txt';
$date = date("d/m-H:i : ");
$eventid = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),1,16);
file_put_contents($filename, array(PHP_EOL, $date, 'eventid=', $eventid, '&', $string), FILE_APPEND);
```

Here is an example of the contents...

```
05/11-03:40 : afgwhdkp4srzvbtc&E.C.P.CssBOR39QXh2Q3Vd8AETrNGSMgczh17L88msrC6FsmykSZFR7XzxbIpFnPuAQdBPbdmShKa6b3bhbSo4gqECUW5W5Y6OoPLQlRA-uvxMTkRblKK4Yb0TM66DHChJALsAQ0fDWeqSKB7XrehW3D52GXtjXxQuWhp5KpKQuf1m3JhI7gp5Rl_t7BabNNMeHLR9ecVJ7lHwZxEoyv9xIzJgXw0-Vi4KCWtwH0JDxxVrlxynyEu830fub4R3gy94wvkm2YLKdPSmsil3NVzUuD4SBHYyLjAaIJYLgslxEyzjLZlf7J4vcu-1zJguCrQp0Iq7JZ_qmRZT
05/11-06:10 : mnztrselg9iv0xao&E.C.P.CssBQ1X9Uz4m6lkvYSQgd4wK95nmwl44LjQ8IhDzthInNbQzSaWsRmB-A-ieyYuixUnEnanc3HMGDyKKHUZi3gf-QAjXk4XtBxgrXB46bOWQ3iPnXjFX4Z2MjB8isA5ID6IcmsCXIay34d74yV72N5Z6LOzXCxJH2vRhpyJfywUiO9Amg-HiieL7oQwVm3igFFE3uVV75qw8GQgueyKHqaiiOlPmYvNAnIL2McGMq_pTYVJC-aPj8jyPw8DdRDzmQpJOthysPqz5rr9ZYd0SBHYyLjAaIO_BO5uaIHfqvWXxDLkK_Alxn6o33Ck-SSquyGuMczwg
```

The format is "Date-Time : eventid&string"
There is a new line for each entry. But I haven't specified a "/n" which your code wants to look for.

'Misunderstood' - in your code below, $str returns string1 and then the remaining contents of the file. I assume because I've not ended each line in output.txt with "/n".

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

> The format is "Date-Time : eventid&string" There is a new line for
> each entry. But I haven't specified a "/n" which your code wants to
> look for.

On my Linux Server the `PHP_EOL` is `\n`
Sometimes when I generate a file for Windows I terminate a line with `"\r\n"`.  
I never use `PHP_EOL`.
You can substitute `\n` with `PHP_EOL`.

---

I generated a test event.txt like this (lines terminated with `\n`):

```
$filename = 'event.txt';
$date = date('m/d H:i : ',time());
$eventid = substr(str_shuffle('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),1,16);
$string = str_shuffle('abcdef');
file_put_contents($filename, array( $date, 'eventid=', $eventid, '&', "$string\n" ), FILE_APPEND);
```

My test file (event.txt):

```
11/08 17:21 : eventid=ug0m8kjw7ntrzs3x&fadbce
11/08 17:21 : eventid=fe6xthnjlmk1ag3y&cdaebf
11/08 17:21 : eventid=6a7sclhg4jd0w9oq&fcebad
11/08 17:21 : eventid=jrfd4ptcq2z1wvoa&ebdafc
```

When generating a JSON string I start with an array and convert it with `json_encode()`

My Code:

```
$data = explode("\n",file_get_contents("event.txt"));
foreach($data as $line){
  $pos = strpos($line,'&') + 1;
  $array = array('string',substr($line,$pos));
  $jsn = json_encode($array,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  echo "$jsn\n";
}
```

Output:

```
{"string":"fadbce"}
{"string":"cdaebf"}
{"string":"fcebad"}
{"string":"ebdafc"}
{"string":false}
```

I added a trim() to the file and the ["string",false] was eliminated:

```
$data = explode("\n",trim(file_get_contents("event.txt")));
```

I also substituted `\n` with `PHP_EOL` and got the same results.

```
 $data = explode(PHP_EOL,file_get_contents("events.txt"));
```

---

END OF UPDATE

---

Your code (or I) may be making some assumptions that are not true. 
Is there a new line following each parameter? 
Your code thinks so.

I you could post an example or snippet of `output.txt`, that would be a big help.

Let's try this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/output.txt");
$start = strpos($data,$eventid);  // find position of event id
$end = strpos($data,'&',$start);  / find the position of the first '&' following  event id
$query = substr($data,$start,$end-$start);  // grab query parameter 1
```

Notice the first `strpos()` had not third paramter.  
Where the second (`$end=`) had a third parameter.

If you have any questions, just ask, as I do not know your level of expertise.

Now I need to know what follows this query string we are parsing. Assuming it is a query string.
It is very important to know what comes after the string being parsed.

I may be easier to extract the whole query string and explode it on '&'.

If the query string is terminated with a line feed:

```
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/output.txt");
$start = strpos($data,$eventid);  // find position of event id
$end = strpos($data,"\n",$start);  / find the position of the first '&' following  event id
$str= substr($data,$start,$end-$start);  // grab whole query string
$parameters = explode('&',$str);

$json = json_encode($paramters);
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json;
```

To to troubleshoot your current error add this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
```

Then after `curl_exec()`...

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo "\nheader out:\n" . curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT);
exit;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll add some more information in the original post.

Comment: @Glen  Is your code working now?